# Find max value from a many-to-many relationship in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 3 tables - 
Employee - having columns - id, name, salary 
Project - having columns - id, name, budget 
Assignment - having columns - empId, pid
(These columns refer to employee and project respectively)

```
Employee table looks like
1| A | 1000
2| B | 2000
3| C | 500
4| D | 4000
5| E | 1000

Project
1| XYZ | 50000
2| PQR | 60000
3| ABC | 70000

Assignment 
1|1
2|1
3|3
4|2
5|2
```

I want the SQL query to return employee having max salary in each project

The result set should be something like -

```
Project id|Employee Name|Salary
     1    |      B      | 2000
     2    |      D      | 4000
     3    |      C      | 500
```

I wrote following SQL. But its returning me all the rows. What could be wrong?

```
select p.id, p.name, e.id, e.name, e.salary
FROM 
(
    select e.id, MAX(e.salary) 
    from employee e
    join assignment a on e.id = a.empId
    join project p on p.id = a.pid
    group by e.id
 ) as EmpMAX
 join Employee e on EmpMAX.id = e.id
 join assignment a on a.empId = e.id
 join project p on p.id = a.pid
```

I referred to the following link to come up with the SQL
[SQL Query between 3-tables of a many-to-many relationship](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11714711/sql-query-between-3-tables-of-a-many-to-many-relationship)

I am using MySQL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT p.*,e.* 
  FROM project p 
  JOIN assignment a 
    ON a.pid = p.id 
  JOIN employee e 
    ON e.id = a.empid 
  JOIN 
     ( SELECT p.id
            , MAX(salary) max_salary
         FROM project p 
         JOIN assignment a 
           ON a.pid = p.id 
         JOIN employee e 
           ON e.id = a.empid
        GROUP
           BY id
     ) x
    ON x.id = p.id
   AND max_salary = e.salary;
```

Note: This chooses multiple employees if there are multiple employees with the same (max) salary.

Answer (score 1):

Probably the easiest way is the `substring_index()``group_concat()` trick:

```
select p.projid,
       substring_index(group_concat(e.name order by e.salary desc), ',', 1) as empname,
       max(salary)
from employee e join
     assignment a
     on e.id = a.empId
group by p.projid;
```

Note:  This chooses only one employee if there are multiples with the same salary.